# Loop in value animator cause in crash with java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: java, android, loops, animation, stack-overflow

I using two value animation and in end of one i start another. It is work fine on my tested devices but get `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB` on many devices in live.

this is how i used value animator:

```
 ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawableIcon, "alpha", 255, 0);
 ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawableIcon, "alpha", 0, 255);

    fadeIn.setDuration(300);
    fadeOut.setDuration(300);
    fadeOut.setStartDelay(500);

    fadeIn.start();

    fadeIn.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            fadeOut.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    fadeOut.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            fadeIn.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```

I googled but coul not find any reason and solution. Is any body have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should repeat animation instead of creating a loop dependency between them. Use `AnimatorSet` to do that:

```
    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawableIcon, "alpha", 0, 255);
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawableIcon, "alpha", 255, 0);
    fadeIn.setDuration(300);
    fadeOut.setDuration(300);
    fadeOut.setStartDelay(500);

    animatorSet.playSequentially(fadeIn, fadeOut);
    animatorSet.setDuration(1100);
    animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        private boolean mCanceled;

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            mCanceled = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCanceled = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            if (!mCanceled) {
                animation.start();
            }
        }

    });
    animatorSet.start();
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: What is the diffrence? Instead of two animation you handled them in animationSet and reppeat that set in onAnimationEnd. I do know if this avoid stackOverflow.

Comment: I think one cause is that your loop solution has no finishing mechanism.

Comment: Ok let me check this.

Comment: I have ran it and put the result in answer.

Comment: @Kenji: Is the problem still there?

Comment: As i mentioned in question i could not catch this crash in local devices so I launched the app to see feedbacks.